# Issue with Data Import for Time Series Analysis in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, time-series

I have a datafile saved in csv format as

```
                        a
       2015-06-01  0.812418096
       2015-06-02  1.218755583
       2015-06-03  0.023311681
```

But when I import the data for Time Series Analysis using xts commands, I get the data as

```
            X            a             
    <NA> "2015-06-01" " 0.812418096"
    <NA> "2015-06-02" " 1.218755583"
    <NA> "2015-06-03" " 0.023311681"
```

I want my data to be in the following format to do the time series analysis

```
                        a
       2015-06-01  0.812418096
       2015-06-02  1.218755583
       2015-06-03  0.023311681
```

Commands executed by me

```
    data <- read.csv("x.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  # Datafile name x.csv . It contains 400 rows of data
    data$X <- as.Date(data$X)        
    str(data)
    x <- xts(data, order.by = as.Date(rownames(data),  "%Y%m%d"))
    x
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
data <- read.table(text='             a
       2015-06-01  0.812418096
                 2015-06-02  1.218755583
                 2015-06-03  0.023311681', header=TRUE)
as.xts(data)


                 a
2015-06-01 0.81241810
2015-06-02 1.21875558
2015-06-03 0.02331168
```